# How to enable the indexing options in Outlook 2013 in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

The quick search bar in my Outlook 2013 installation is not working and I tried to configure indexing appropriately. When I go to

```
File - Options - Search - Indexing Options
```

the indexing location table is empty and the button "Modify" is disabled. If I go to "Advanced", I can only use the button "Rebuild" (which doesn't help with my problem), the rest is disabled as well.

It is a fresh installation, not upgraded from an older version. What could be the cause for that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Indexing locations** show **blank** & **modify** option is **grayed out** because your **windows search service** is either **stopped** or **disabled**

To start a stopped or disabled **Windows search service**, do the following

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> & type **services.msc** & press enter
2. Locate Windows Search in the list of services
3. Double click on it to open **Windows Search Service Properties**
4. Make sure the **service startup type** is **automatic(Delayed)** & it is
   **started**

[image: Windows search service automatic delayed start]

Answer (score -3):

I see nobody has answered this and it took me hour and hours of painful search to finally come to the conclusion that Microsoft screwed all relying on Search with Win7 and Office 2013.

It’s simply "disabled" as Office 2013 is built for the useless win8 (only)
So if you are like me and most others that prefers win7, then say good bye to the Search functionality.

There is of Couse the 99% useless "search folder" option.... but that is en general useless and time consuming.

I have only 2 advice:

1) Go back to Office 2010
2) Get a 3rd party Indexer like Lookeen, Filelocater or such.
Both are good.... but not as "handy" as the old Win Search.

Comment: Your answer is totally incorrect. Office 2013 is not built for use in Windows 8 only & Search in Office 2013 works just fine. Even if we go by you and say Search only works with Office 2010, why are  you recommending a third party indexer ??